# What does it mean to say that a method reads a byte of data?

Tags: java, api, byte, java-io

I am going through the oracle API for [`java.io.RandomAccessFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) class.

There's method called read() in the class which reads byte of data from the file passed to the constructor:-

> public int read()
>            throws IOException
>
> Reads a byte of data from this file. The byte is returned as an
>   integer in the range 0 to 255 (0x00-0x0ff). This method blocks if no
>   input is yet available.
>
> Although RandomAccessFile is not a subclass of InputStream, this
>   method behaves in exactly the same way as the InputStream.read()
>   method of InputStream.
>
> Returns:
>       the next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the file has been reached. Throws:
>       IOException - if an I/O error occurs. Not thrown if end-of-file has been reached.

I am confused, does it mean to say that it reads 8 bits of data from the file passed to the constructor and convert the read contents to int.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It reads "an octet of data" (octet = 8 bits) from the source .. in this case the data would be from an opened File as it is a RandomAccessFile implementation .. (the return type is an `int` merely so it can return `-1` on EOF, otherwise it will be `[0, 256)`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is confusing you, exactly?

Yes, it reads one byte of data, which is 8 bits, and returns it as an integer value in the inclusive range 0..255.  So if the file in question happens to be a text file, and the first character is a capital 'A', `read()` will return 65.

It returns an `int` instead of a `byte` so that it can return the full range 0..255 as a positive number, and still have -1 available as a sentinel value for end-of-file (though arguably an exception would have been a better way to do that).

Comment: +1,  i wasn't sure what does a byte means in terms of reading from a file; but the size of the byte is (8 bit) and range -128 to 127

Comment: Yup.  In Java, a `byte` is a signed value from -128 to 127.  Other languages have an unsigned version with a range of 0 to 255. In English, a "byte" is any 8-bit value, usually in memory or storage; such a value in the process of being transmitted is often called an "octet" instead. And in really old (pre-1980, at least) papers you can find "byte" used to refer to the native word size of a machine, no matter how many bits that is.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't have unsigned types. A byte, when typically interpreted as unsigned, is an integer in the range [0..255]. `read()` also uses -1 to indicate an error. So you need a type with at least 257 distinct values. The Java `int` type is a 32-bit signed integer. So the documentation is saying that it's passing either an 8-bit unsigned value of the byte read or an error indicator, and it's passing that in a 32-bit signed return type as a container.

Comment: Brain fart on short vs. int. Fixed.